# Query regarding use of PLA in 3D printing

Tags: 3d-printing

Just a general question for engineers who have been working with 3D printers,

- what type of alternatives are available for PLA? Are they efficient (economically or quality wise) than it, if yes then why aren't they popular?
- what challinges are faced in existing technology(ie PLA filaments) (mainly related to material quality)?

Comment: There are many, many 3D printer forums where I'm sure this topic has been beaten to death.

Comment: PLA is probably the most basic material for filament printers.  "Alternatives" have different properties (usually more issues from thermal expansion) and some even have different requirements (printing ABS without a heated bed is not recommended). https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/77/23523

Comment: "Alternatives" in what manner? For the same 3D printer? Or for 3D printing in general? Because there are many types of 3D printers and some can 3D print metal.

Answer (score 1):

PLA is the most common because its cheap and easy to use. It's also one of the only filaments that can achieve reasonable results without a heated bed (or heated enclosure).

There are numerous other filaments with various pros and cons. It would be silly to list them here because a simple internet search yield *hundreds* of just such comparisons.

It would be incorrect to say that they are not popular. PETG for example is very popular, even if it's less so than PLA.

There is no challenge existing with material *quality* that I'm aware of. Cheap filiment is available that is very precise and which produces consistant results. The challenge is material properties.

FDM prints, are in general fairly weak compared to other materials like injection molded plastic, metal, or even wood in some cases.

One reasons the 3D printed material is inferior is the layer by layer deposition. This orients the polymer chains along the horizontal axis, which has the effect of weakening the vertical axis. The layer adhesion is also not perfect, which further weakens the same axis.

Another reason is that filament must balance material strength with printability. PETG for example is just PET (like soda bottles) that is modified with glycol to give it a lower melting point. This is a compromise that makes it easier to print, but which reduces the material properties. Many if not most common plastics that have desirable material properties are very hard to print due to warping, stress cracking, layer adhesion or other issues.